# Getting related tags in elasticsearch with related tags query

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way to find related tags to a tag via tags often seen on other documents featuring this tag? Just to be clear this is not to find similar documents but similar tags. The document would have the tags in a tag field with mapping set to `keywords`. Would this be possible in elasticsearch or would i need to create new documents representing tags?

Comment: How do you define ***similar*** tags here. Based on edit distance, substring or synonyms? Could you please share few sample data. That would be useful.

Comment: @OpsterESNinja-Kamal similar tags would be "tags often seen on other documents featuring this tag". So based on "cyberpunk" you would find "sci-fi" because there are documents tagged with "cyberpunk, sci-fi", and less for other genres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use terms aggregation.

```
client.search({
  index: 'indexname',
  body: {
    query: {
      bool: {
        filter: [{
          "term": {
            "tags": "tagname"
          }
        }]
      }
    },
    "aggregations": {
      "tags": {
        "terms": { "field": "tags" },
      }
    }
  }
}, (err, result) => {
  if (err) console.log(err)
  console.log(result.body, result.body.aggregations.tags.buckets)
})
```